# I'm working with React Route, and I have a random string, but when I do click on the link page works but when a do click again doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-router, react-dom

I have a simple menu and I have a page with a random context only for tests.
Here my index.js

```
const Route       = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link        = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const HashRouter  = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const Routes      = ReactRouterDOM.Routes;

// create context
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);

function Spa() {

    return (
    <HashRouter>
    <div>
    <h1>Routing - Hello World</h1>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link> --
    <Link to="/about/">About</Link> --
    <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
    <hr />
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ users: ["peter"] }}>
    <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={ <Home />} />
    <Route path="/about/" element={ <About />} />
    <Route path="/products/" element={ <Products />} />
    </Routes>
    </UserContext.Provider>
    </div>
    </HashRouter>
    );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
    <Spa/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

and this is my products.js

```
    const ctx = React.useContext(UserContext);  
    ctx.users.push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));

    return (
    <div>
    <h3>Products Component</h3>
    <p>List of the the product we make</p>
    {JSON.stringify(ctx.users)}
    </div>
   );
}
```

my problem is that when I do click on the products menu the fist time the random works, but if I do again doesn't works, I have to change of link, for example login and return again to products for random works.

Someone knows what could be the problem?

I am using
React-dom-16.8
History-5
React-Router-dom-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. Linking to a route with the same path and state/etc is effectively a non-op. It won't trigger a navigation and it won't trigger the routed component to rerender.
2. `ctx.users.push(Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));` is an unintentional side-effect and also won't trigger a rerender. You only see the mutation after navigating away and back to `"/products"`.

## Solution

1. `users` should reside in *some* react state so when it's updated it can trigger React components to rerender. Pass the `users` state ***and*** the state updater (*or some callback to update state*) as the `UserContext` value.
2. Pass *some* "random" state value in the link such that it will trigger the navigation action. Check for state in an `useEffect` to help trigger the effect to update the `users` state.

### Suggestions

Spa

```
const Spa = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(["peter"]);
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h1>Routing - Hello World</h1>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> --
        <Link to="/about/">About</Link> --
        <Link
          to="/products"
          state={{ value: Math.random() }} // <-- random state to trigger navigation
        >
          Products
        </Link>
        <hr />
        <UserContext.Provider value={{ users, setUsers }}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about/" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/products/" element={<Products />} />
          </Routes>
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Products

```
const Products = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { users, setUsers } = useContext(UserContext);

  // "Listen" for updates to route state to trigger effect
  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers((users) => [...users, Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)]);
  }, [state, setUsers]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Products Component</h3>
      <p>List of the the product we make</p>
      {JSON.stringify(users)}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit im-working-with-react-route-and-i-have-a-random-string-but-when-i-do-click-on]

Answer (score 0):

Use `BrowserRouter` instead of `HashRouter`